# Which form is correct: "Ein Moment" or "Einen Moment"

Tags: article

I have seen *Einen Moment!* almost all the time and I can't comprehend why it is written like this when at the start of a sentence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This depends on whether nominative case or accusative case is needed. In phrases as

> Einen Moment, bitte!

you can see there's no verb. It's an ellipsis, the complete sentence is

> *Warten Sie* einen Moment, bitte!

In that complete sentence, *Sie* is the subject, and *einen Moment* is an optional accusative object to the verb *warten*, which specifies the duration.

> Warten Sie einen Monat.

---

In addition, word order doesn't determine subject or object in German. One could write

> Einen Moment warten Sie jetzt bitte noch, ja?

and still, *einen Moment* would be an accusative object, and *Sie* the subject.

---

The nominative case is needed for subjects

> So ein Moment kehrt nicht wieder.

and predicatives:

> Dies war der Moment, auf den er gewartet hatte.

Comment: Danke vielmals!! Ich verstehe jetzt

Answer (score 1):

Both forms exist, but are different grammatical cases. Therefore, which form is correct depends on what you want to say.

> **Nominative:**
> ein Moment
>
> *Das ist ein Moment der Ruhe.*
>
> **Genitive:**
> eines Moments
>
> *Er tat es während eines günstigen Moments.*
>
> **Dative:**
> einem Moment
>
> *Er tat es in einem günstigen Moment.*
>
> **Accusative:**
> einen Moment
>
> *Warten Sie bitte einen Moment!*

Answer (score 1):

In German, there is a whole set of utterances that contain a noun phrase in the accusative despite the fact that there is no verb or preposition governing the accusative present.

> Gut**en** Morgen/Tag/Abend.
>   Gut**en** Appetit!
>   Ein**en** angenehmen Tag noch!
>   Gut**en** Rutsch! (said on New Year's Eve)

In the above examples, think of a corresponding sentence starting with *Ich wünsche dir/euch/Ihnen…*, with the accusative governed by *wünschen*. In your example, *wünschen* doesn't fit, but you can think of a corresponding sentence starting with *warten*.

Comment: Vielen Dank fur Ihre hilfe!

Answer (score 0):

Definite time expressions always appear in the Akkusativ case. Wie lange warst du in Berlin? Einen Monat.

Comment: „Wann fährst du nach Berlin? – In einem Monat.“

Comment: The proposition „in“ takes this out of the definite time rule (where their are no prepositions or definite articles or indefinite articles used as well). It Is a useful rule for learner to keep definite time in mind, unless you toss in a proposition like in or something, then you have to follow the rules on case and they are different, as in „in einem Monat.“